# Android not writing file, or the file is getting removed somehow?

Tags: java, android

Trying to write an xls file but it either won't write or it keeps getting deleted. system reports some type of file is being deleted but I'm really not sure. I'm using apache poi to write the xls file and don't have any problems using it with a regular java application.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class Excel_Constructor extends Activity  {



public  void main(String[] args) {

    FileOutputStream fos = null;


    Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

    try {

        fos =openFileOutput("Test.xls", this.MODE_PRIVATE);
        workbook.write(fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "There was a problem making the file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


public void saveData() {
```

Logcat:

```
05-18 15:46:38.199      803-829/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed
com.example.liam.quickreport20/.Setup: +1s502ms
05-18 15:46:40.329      803-925/system_process D/TaskPersister﹕  
removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=235_task.xml
05-18 15:46:40.330      803-925/system_process D/TaskPersister﹕ 
removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=235_task_thumbnail.png
05-18 15:47:58.058      803-803/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing  
1608:com.android.externalstorage/u0a6 (adj 15): empty for 1817s
05-18 15:47:58.082     803-1211/system_process W/libprocessgroup﹕ failed to  
open /acct/uid_10006/pid_1608/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
05-18 15:49:31.729        82-82/? D/Genyd﹕ Received Set Clipboard
05-18 15:49:31.729        82-82/? D/Genymotion﹕ Received Set Clipboard
05-18 15:50:05.405        82-82/? D/Genyd﹕ Received Set Clipboard
```

Comment: If the file doesn't exist, don't you need to create it first using "new File("Test.xls").createNewFile();"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to replaceyour try-catch block with this one:

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {

            String str_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File file ;
            file = new File(str_path, "Test.xls");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);


            workbook.write(fos);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Excel Sheet Generated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```